# SSH localhost authentication failed mac

Tags: macos, authentication, networking, ssh, localhost

Testing ssh functionality on my Mac and wondering why SSH into localhost just with the command:

```
$ ssh localhost
```

Prompts me for a password, and responds with

```
Password: 
localhost: Authentication failed.
```

on the first attempt (after entering correct local password), and consistently follows up with more prompts if I enter the wrong password or nothing:

```
$ ssh localhost
Password:
Password:
Password:
squid@localhost's password:
Received disconnect from ::1 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed.
```

The behavior is different if I enter the right password, so I know my password is correct. But why would authentication still fail? Please help!

Comment: maybe password authentication is not allowed (good choice!).

Comment: Add `-v` options to your ssh command: `ssh -v localhost`

Comment: UPDATE: It's a setting with local file sharing. Not sure why but out of the box configurations don't allow for an ssh into localhost. 

To fix: Open System Preferences -> Sharing -> Check File Sharing (make sure your user is included)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE : Figured it out. It's a setting with local file sharing. Not sure why but out of the box configurations don't allow for an ssh into localhost. To fix: Open System Preferences -> Sharing -> Check Remote Login (make sure your user is included)